# При выходе с приложения не сохраняются данные в PlayerPrefs Unity Android

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал приложение в `Unity` на `iOS` всё работает, поменял платформу на Android, так всё сразу упало, я сохранял данные при выходе,

```
    public void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        SaveDataSudoku ();//метод с PlayerPrefsX... 
    }
```

Прочитал в статье что для `Android-a` нужно сохранять в другом моменте

```
public void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
        SaveDataSudoku ();
    }
}
```

Но всё равно не работает как надо, не всегда сохраняет...

Comment: а вызываете команду PlayerPrefs.Save() ? Собственно, она пишет на диск данные.

Comment: тестировал и с ней тоже... никакой разницы

Comment: Может проблема не в playersprefs? а в SaveDataSudoku  например

Answer (score 0):

Для андроида попробуйте вызывать метод c PlayerPrefs (например, PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("positionX", position.x);) дополнительно к OnApplicationPause(bool) в OnApplicationFocus(bool)